# In Black Clover, is Yuno is an elf?

Tags: black-clover

In the latest episode of Black Clover (ep100), Yuno seems like he's still himself even having his body used for the reincarnation magic of the elves.

Does it mean that he is an elf and his true power just awoken because of the reincarnation magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No yuno is not an elf and not Licht child.

Black clover Season 3 Episode 120

> Yuno realises the elf possessing him was Licht and Tetia’s unborn son,
>  and Licht thanks Yuno for allowing him to meet him.

Answer (score 0):

No, he is an elf at that point in the series due to the reincarnation magic but he isn't a true elf with an elf bloodline. He is like himself because he has a strong will and that is why an elf hasn't taken over his body.